# Split an integer into digits to compute an ISBN checksum

Tags: python, integer, decimal

I'm writing a program which calculates the check digit of an ISBN number. I have to read the user's input (nine digits of an ISBN) into an integer variable, and then multiply the last digit by 2, the second last digit by 3 and so on. How can I "split" the integer into its constituent digits to do this? As this is a basic homework exercise I am not supposed to use a list.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Just create a string out of it.

```
myinteger = 212345
number_string = str(myinteger)
```

That's enough. Now you can iterate over it:

```
for ch in number_string:
    print ch # will print each digit in order
```

Or you can slice it:

```
print number_string[:2] # first two digits
print number_string[-3:] # last three digits
print number_string[3] # forth digit
```

---

Or better, don't convert the user's input to an integer (the user types a string)

```
isbn = raw_input()
for pos, ch in enumerate(reversed(isbn)):
    print "%d * %d is %d" % pos + 2, int(ch), int(ch) * (pos + 2)
```

For more information read a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tut).

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: @nosklo Unfortunately Tutorial Url is broken. Do you mind editing ?

Comment: when you print digits, you will get an extra 1 at the beginning, how can I solve that?

Answer (score 77):

```
while number:
    digit = number % 10

    # do whatever with digit

    # remove last digit from number (as integer)
    number //= 10
```

On each iteration of the loop, it removes the last digit from number, assigning it to `digit`. 
It's in reverse, starts from the last digit, finishes with the first

Comment: I added an explanation. If you don't see how it works, take a piece of paper and go through the process step-by-step for a number of choice.

Comment: It extracts the digits from the given number, assuming base 10, starting with the least significant digit. This is a mathematical approach instead of a Pythonic one. An approach that will work in any language. And an approach that will also work when one is interested in the digits of a number written in another base (unlike the other solutions posted here). Hence: +1.

Comment: this is absolutely insane and is not working in py3k (fix is tiny though)

Comment: @SilentGhost: the examples above apply int to single characters resulting from iterating over the result of applying str. It is str that returns a base 10 representation of the number.

Comment: @Stephan202: as it's fairly clear from the question OP starts with a string, so he doesn't need to convert to integer; ISBN is using base 10 digits; if you know the base there are enough buil-in function that let you convert resulting base-10 int to you base-X int.

Comment: @Alexander: When you can just iterate over the string already entered by the user, instead of converting it to an integer and then doing arithmetic on it. From "Zen of Python": Simple is better than complex.

Comment: Why not use a generator? yield the `digit`

Comment: +1 for this is actually 2-3 times faster then converting to string

Comment: I can't believe people don't see how practical this solution is.

Answer (score 23):

```
list_of_ints = [int(i) for i in str(ISBN)]
```

Will give you a ordered list of ints. Of course, given duck typing, you might as well work with str(ISBN).

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, this list isn't sorted in the sense of being ascending or descending, but it does have a defined order (sets, dictionaries, etc in python in theory don't, although in practice the order tends to be fairly reliable). If you want to sort it:

list_of_ints.sort()

is your friend. Note that sort() sorts in place (as in, actually changes the order of the existing list) and doesn't return a new list.

Comment: or: list_of_ints = map(int, str(ISBN))

Comment: yay, paffnucy! Let's not forget map/reduce/zip et al.!

Comment: "sorted list of ints"? in what sense is it going to be "sorted"?

Comment: @Daren - not always faster, but usually more readable (excluding reduce() ^^)

Comment: Sorted in the sense that it has a defined order, as opposed to say a tuple or a set. I'll edit that into the answer...

Comment: Yeah, I realised as soon as I submitted it. You'll notice I didn't mention them in the edit.

Answer (score 14):

On Older versions of Python...

```
map(int,str(123))
```

On New Version 3k

```
list(map(int,str(123)))
```

Comment: @Lord British, hard to say, since both are designed for different versions, i'd suppose Py3k should be faster (hopefully,hehe)

Answer (score 4):

```
(number/10**x)%10
```

You can use this in a loop, where number is the full number, x is each iteration of the loop (0,1,2,3,...,n) with n being the stop point. x = 0 gives the ones place, x = 1 gives the tens, x = 2 gives the hundreds, and so on. Keep in mind that this will give the value of the digits from right to left, so this might not be the for an ISBN but it will still isolate each digit.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to string and map over it with the int() function.

```
map(int, str(1231231231))
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion version:

```
def int_digits(n):
    return [n] if n<10 else int_digits(n/10)+[n%10]
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting to `str` is definitely slower then dividing by 10.

`map` is sligthly slower than list comprehension:

```
convert to string with map 2.13599181175
convert to string with list comprehension 1.92812991142
modulo, division, recursive 0.948769807816
modulo, division 0.699964046478
```

These times were returned by the following code on my laptop:

```
foo = """\
def foo(limit):
    return sorted(set(map(sum, map(lambda x: map(int, list(str(x))), map(lambda x: x * 9, range(limit))))))

foo(%i)
"""

bar = """\
def bar(limit):
    return sorted(set([sum([int(i) for i in str(n)]) for n in [k *9 for k in range(limit)]]))

bar(%i)
"""

rac = """\
def digits(n):
    return [n] if n<10 else digits(n / 10)+[n %% 10]

def rabbit(limit):
    return sorted(set([sum(digits(n)) for n in [k *9 for k in range(limit)]]))

rabbit(%i)
"""

rab = """\
def sum_digits(number):
  result = 0
  while number:
    digit = number %% 10
    result += digit
    number /= 10
  return result

def rabbit(limit):
    return sorted(set([sum_digits(n) for n in [k *9 for k in range(limit)]]))

rabbit(%i)
"""


import timeit

print "convert to string with map", timeit.timeit(foo % 100, number=10000)
print "convert to string with list comprehension", timeit.timeit(bar % 100, number=10000)
print "modulo, division, recursive", timeit.timeit(rac % 100, number=10000)
print "modulo, division", timeit.timeit(rab % 100, number=10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

After own diligent searches I found several solutions, where each has advantages and disadvantages. Use the most suitable for your task.

All examples tested with the CPython 3.5 on the operation system GNU/Linux Debian 8.

---

**Using a recursion**

Code

```
def get_digits_from_left_to_right(number, lst=None):
    """Return digits of an integer excluding the sign."""

    if lst is None:
        lst = list()

    number = abs(number)

    if number < 10:
        lst.append(number)
        return tuple(lst)

    get_digits_from_left_to_right(number // 10, lst)
    lst.append(number % 10)

    return tuple(lst)
```

Demo

```
In [121]: get_digits_from_left_to_right(-64517643246567536423)
Out[121]: (6, 4, 5, 1, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 2, 3)

In [122]: get_digits_from_left_to_right(0)
Out[122]: (0,)

In [123]: get_digits_from_left_to_right(123012312312321312312312)
Out[123]: (1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
```

---

**Using the function `divmod`**

Code

```
def get_digits_from_right_to_left(number):
    """Return digits of an integer excluding the sign."""

    number = abs(number)

    if number < 10:
        return (number, )

    lst = list()

    while number:
        number, digit = divmod(number, 10)
        lst.insert(0, digit)

    return tuple(lst)
```

Demo

```
In [125]: get_digits_from_right_to_left(-3245214012321021213)
Out[125]: (3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3)

In [126]: get_digits_from_right_to_left(0)
Out[126]: (0,)

In [127]: get_digits_from_right_to_left(9999999999999999)
Out[127]: (9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
```

---

**Using a construction `tuple(map(int, str(abs(number)))`**

```
In [109]: tuple(map(int, str(abs(-123123123))))
Out[109]: (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

In [110]: tuple(map(int, str(abs(1412421321312))))
Out[110]: (1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2)

In [111]: tuple(map(int, str(abs(0))))
Out[111]: (0,)
```

---

**Using the function `re.findall`**

```
In [112]: tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d', str(1321321312))))
Out[112]: (1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2)

In [113]: tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d', str(-1321321312))))
Out[113]: (1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2)

In [114]: tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d', str(0))))
Out[114]: (0,)
```

---

**Using the module `decimal`**

```
In [117]: decimal.Decimal(0).as_tuple().digits
Out[117]: (0,)

In [118]: decimal.Decimal(3441120391321).as_tuple().digits
Out[118]: (3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 9, 1, 3, 2, 1)

In [119]: decimal.Decimal(-3441120391321).as_tuple().digits
Out[119]: (3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 9, 1, 3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the body of this loop to do whatever you want to with the digits

```
for digit in map(int, str(my_number)):
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made this program and here is the bit of code that actually calculates the check digit in my program

```
    #Get the 10 digit number
    number=input("Please enter ISBN number: ")

    #Explained below
    no11 = (((int(number[0])*11) + (int(number[1])*10) + (int(number[2])*9) + (int(number[3])*8) 
           + (int(number[4])*7) + (int(number[5])*6) + (int(number[6])*5) + (int(number[7])*4) +
           (int(number[8])*3) + (int(number[9])*2))/11)

    #Round to 1 dp
    no11 = round(no11, 1)

    #explained below
    no11 = str(no11).split(".")

    #get the remainder and check digit
    remainder = no11[1]
    no11 = (11 - int(remainder))

    #Calculate 11 digit ISBN
    print("Correct ISBN number is " + number + str(no11))
```

Its a long line of code, but it splits the number up, multiplies the digits by the appropriate amount, adds them together and divides them by 11, in one line of code. The .split() function just creates a list (being split at the decimal) so you can take the 2nd item in the list and take that from 11 to find the check digit. This could also be made even more efficient by changing these two lines:

```
    remainder = no11[1]
    no11 = (11 - int(remainder))
```

To this:

```
    no11 = (11 - int(no11[1]))
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/975039/18866) answer but more a more "pythonic" way to iterate over the digis would be:

```
while number:
    # "pop" the rightmost digit
    number, digit = divmod(number, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a one-liner list of digits...

```
ldigits = lambda n, l=[]: not n and l or l.insert(0,n%10) or ldigits(n/10,l)
```

Comment: use `//` for int division...on Py3k `/` returns a float.

Comment: @st0le: I don,t use p3k, no numpy & no psyco = p3k sucks.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** 165

**Method:** brute-force! Here is a tiny bit of Python (version 2.7) code to count'em all.

```
from math import sqrt, floor
is_ps = lambda x: floor(sqrt(x)) ** 2 == x
count = 0
for n in range(1002, 10000, 3):
    if n % 11 and is_ps(sum(map(int, str(n)))):
        count += 1
        print "#%i: %s" % (count, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assuming you want to get the *i*-th least significant digit from an integer number *x*, you can try:

```
(abs(x)%(10**i))/(10**(i-1))
```

I hope it helps.