# I keep getting the error message 'TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable' in python

Tags: python

I have tested this code several times and keep getting the same error message.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the code which has the problem:

```
guess = int(guess)
number = int(number)
if guess[0] == number[0]:
    ## other (correct)code goes here
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in the line `if guess[0] == number[0]:`? Both are numbers! If you want to test the first digit, convert them to `str`

Comment: Why are you writing the `[0]`s? That is to say, what's the reasoning in not making this `guess == number`?

Comment: I want it to say if the first characters are the same

Comment: @annieapple2000, then you can't use `int()` on the line above -- after you cast something to an int, it's just one number, not a stream of characters any more, so you can't subscript to refer to those characters.

Comment: @annieapple2000 Then convert both to `str` instead of `int`. Change the calls there!

Comment: ok but i tried str(...) too but that didnt work either...

Comment: Well, sure -- if your other, unshown code doesn't work with strings it won't "just work", but you'll need to find and address those issues separately.

Comment: `if str(guess)[:1] == str(number)[:1]` would cast to strings only for the one line without changing anything else.

Comment: BTW, the clarification we've gotten about your intent in the comments really should be edited into the question.

Comment: @annieapple2000 [**just look at this post.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974952/split-an-integer-into-digits-to-compute-an-isbn-checksum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Int is a scalar type, not a collection type, like a list or array, so you cannot do access an element of an `int` by subscripting it with `int[0]`.

Subscripting a `str` would work, but its hard to figure out if thats really what you want based on the tiny snippet.

```
guess = str(guess)
number = str(number)
if guess[0] == number[0]:
```

Answer (score 2):

You changed what were presumably strings into integers. They aren't subscriptable. If you want to check the first digit, keep them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the nth entry of a number. You can only do that with string and list and something else, but not numbers.