# Python: Unique numbers in string

Tags: python

I would like to retain the unique integer in the second column and print the entry in the previous (first) column. But I am having trouble converting a string to an integer and get the error: **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

**Input File**

```
    A     1     108.80
    A     1       8.33
    B     2      45.10
    B     2       3.96
    B     2       3.94
    A     3       1.96
    A     3       2.94
```

**Output**

```
A
B
A
```

**Script**

```
with open('test.pdb') as infile:
        for line in infile:
                data = int(line.split()[1])
                seen = set()
                for number in range(data):
                        unique = [x for x in number if x not in seen]   
                        seen.update(unique)
                        print(unique)
```

Comment: What do you imagine `[x for x in number if x not in seen]` will give? Particularly `for x in number`, given that `number` is an `int` since you say `for number in range(data)`.

Comment: If youa re getting an error, post the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: there is an error in your list comprehension `unique = [x for x in number if x not in seen]` , it is trying to loop over the variable `number` which is not  a list in your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split an integer into digits to compute an ISBN checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974952/split-an-integer-into-digits-to-compute-an-isbn-checksum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you (probably) want:

```
seen = set()
with open('test.pdb') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        unique, data = line.split()[0:2]
        if data not in seen:
            print(unique)
            seen.add(data)
```

Comment: Yours is better!

Comment: rather than slicing `line.split()`, it's probably easier to use tuple unpacking (`unique, data, *_ = line.split()`) though that's only valid in Python3.4 (maybe 3.5?) or higher

Answer (score 1):

Given that example, here is a list comprehension to process that:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    seen=set()
    print '\n'.join([c1 for c1,c2 in (line.split()[0:2] for line in f) 
                                   if not (c2 in seen or seen.add(c2))])
```

Prints:

```
A
B
A
```